# Mismatch between python3 version from command line and version in /usr/local/lib

Tags: python-3.x

When I start python3 in terminal, it runs python 3.6.5.

However, when I look in /usr/local/lib, I see python 3.7 and all it's site-packages.

Why is there a discrepancy? Shouldn't the version always match when I update? Does this matter?

Comment: Type `which python3` and it will display the real location - you have more than one python3 installed.

Answer (score 0):

The command `which python` will tell you the path to the executable that is being chosen. Use `echo $PATH` to see which directories are checked for files to run and in which order - this should help you to understand which file is being chosen and why.